# Projecting 6D cartesian coordinates to lower dimension

Tags: geometry, visualization

I've got a noisy set of points that lie on/near a unit 6-sphere. I want to visualise their proximity to the sphere in some way. The only way I can come up with now is a histogram of the norm of the points (See below). For 2D and 3D this is simple, but is there a way to do this for higher dimensions other than a histogram?

In other words, is there a way to project 6 cartesian coordinates $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)$ with length 1 onto a unit circle/3-sphere?

[image: hypersphere proximity]

Comment: The norm histogram does present the distribution of norms quite well. What else you can/may want to show probably depends on the details of the distribution. For example, if the directions of points are truly uniformly distrubuted (say, w.r.t. to a uniform measure on $S^5$) then there may be not much else to show. If the data has preferred directions, say they tend to concentrate on a certain 4-dimensional cross section of the sphere, then you can find such subspaces with statistical methods, and then plan a visualization that shows such a tendency.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know for sure, but IIRC finding a [Karhunen-Loéve basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem) would reveal such tendencies (if they exist).

Comment: You can, of course, do things like 
$$(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_6)\mapsto(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2},\sqrt{x_3^2+x_4^2},\sqrt{x_5^2+x_6^2}),$$ or pair up the coordinates some other way. That will map the 6D unit sphere to the first octant of the 3D unit sphere. But this distorts a number of things. Oh, and KL may be overkill here, all you probably need is the covariance matrix - I plead guilty of a bit of name dropping. Ask someone well versed in stats.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know all those names ;) Covariance matrix is indeed something I did not think of. That is indeed smart. KL is also a good measure since the points are indeed normally distributed.

Comment: Icosahedral quasilattice, maybe?